# Hiding Command Messages in a Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

In a `bash` script, I'm using tools like `conntrack` and `tcpdump` to output results to a file, but wish to hide the standard message displayed on the first output line on the command line after executing the command/script.

message:

`conntrack v1.0.0 (conntrack-tools): 6 flow entries have been shown.`

After reading the `bash` man page, I've tried things like:

```
conntrack -L|grep "dport=6439" &> /tmp/file
```

No matter what redirect option I try, the `conntrack` message stating the number of flow entries is always displayed in the shell where I execute the script.  Same thing goes for `tcpdump` where it lists the capturing device and number of packets captured, etc.

Of course, I could add `clear` after the `conntrack` or `tcpdump` commands to quickly hide the output, but that solution is ugly.

How can I hide these kinds of messages?

Comment: This can be useful for you too http://stackoverflow.com/a/549776/792066

Comment: side note: `/dev/null` would probably be better

Comment: `/dev/null` wouldn't apply here because I want to redirect the standard output to file `/tmp/file/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those messages are printed as errors (stderr) rather than regular output (stdout).

Only stdout gets piped, not stderr. So by having `&> /tmp/file` after grep, you are only merging the stdout and stderr output of `grep` itself, it will not merge the stderr of `conntrack`

For your example, you probably want something like:

```
conntrack -L 2>&1 | grep "dport=6439" > /tmp/file
```

stderr is file descriptor 2, and stdout is file descriptor 1. `2>&1` merges stderr into stdout.

By sticking `2>&1` on `conntrack`, the output gets merged before it is piped to `grep`. There is no need to merge again on `grep`.